# Making rice in a thermos flask

Tags: rice

Would mixing white rice grains with boiling water and pouring the mix into a thermos flask and letting it stay there for an hour work (to make edible rice)?

p.s I don't have a thermos flask to try and check but if this technique has chances of working, it would be useful while traveling when boiling water is available but not cooked rice. i.e. use an industrial heat gun to heat up the water and also point that heat gun inside the empty flask for a couple of seconds to heat it as well before pouring the water, add rice and get out of the place in 2 minutes

Comment: You should look up ‘thermal cookers’ which are like a thermos, but actually intended to cook in like what you’re asking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several sources of information on line that illustrate people cooking rice in a thermos flask.  It should be easy to google, and it certainly looks possible.  They basically do as you suggest, add boiling water to rice and seal.  Some use instant rice, others I've seen use brown rice.  Time until done (or at least until they used it) seems to vary quite widely.  I would think you could read these posts, and then experiment with your own thermos and specific rice.